# How to filter from a combobox in Sencha-touch?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to filter in a combobox under Sencha Touch framework but I am not loading correct the records in the list.

My code is:

```
onTemplatesFilterChoosen: function(field, newValue, oldValue){
  var store = Ext.getStore('Customers'),
        templatesStore = store.getAt(0).templates(), //get the associated store
        text = field.getRecord().data.text;
    templatesStore.clearFilter();
//here the code to filter main store based in records of the associated store
}
```

But it is not working correctly and my `store.getCount()`for example is 0, showing a empty list.

In my main model I am adding a new model based in the properties of the filter called `"CustomerTemplateModel"`

```
associations: [
        {
            type: 'hasMany',
            associatedModel: 'x.customer.model.CustomerTemplateModel',
            ownerModel: 'x.customer.model.CustomerModel',
            associationKey: 'templates',
            autoLoad: true,
            filterProperty: 'value',
            name: 'templates'
        }
    ]
```

And here the model associated:

```
   Ext.define('x.customer.model.CustomerTemplateModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires:[
    ],
    config: {
        useCache: false,
        rootProperty: 'templates',
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'text',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'value',
                type: 'string'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Sorry, I have no used fiddle... :-(

Comment: can you post here your complete code to make it resolve?

Comment: I have added my associated model..but I don´t have more code..

Comment: I have edited the code of the controller @Mohit